# how to read the message posted into the queue using NServiceBus from a Web Application using VS in C#

Tags: nservicebus

I have posted a message into the queue using NServiceBus and have read it into a class project with the help of the Host.exe, however when i try to implement the same in a webapplication it is not able to invoke the Handler. Thus i cannot read the message that has been posted. 
Basically what i want is I have 2 web applications in a solution to post and read messages posted by the other.
please can you help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you called .LoadMessageHandlers() after .UnicastBus() in your startup code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
yes i do have LoadMessageHandlers().. Also, In web applications do i need the HOst to run in the background? Because if i run the host in the backgroud then the aspx page will not start on run.... Im facing a problem there.

Comment: You don't need the NServiceBus.Host.exe running in the background if you're doing your own hosting.

Comment: is there any website or example which implements communication between 2 webapplications in the same solution in VS2008. Im having a lot of problem implementing the same since im new to NServiceBus.
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The async pages sample shows how to host NServiceBus in a web application. You'd configure each one to have its own queue, and then you can do standard request/response and publish/subscribe between them - just like is shown in the other samples.

Comment: Saw that example and have tried out my example using the same. Thanks a lot. Also wanted to know if i have 2 applications on different servers would it work with the express edition or would i need the paid version? Sorry to shoot you which questions. Im a beginner with NServiceBus hence the numerous doubts.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to get a license to use it in more than one server.